# creating a list/ vector of text from shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Can we create a vector/ list of inputs given from shiny? I would like to create a vector of string which stores all the action taken from input in shiny.

here is the example code, so as soon as we change the input, the output gets change in the same line.

```
require(shiny)

runApp(list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("censusVis"),
  sidebarPanel(
    helpText("Create demographic maps with 
             information from the 2010 US Census."),
    selectInput("var", 
                label = "Choose a variable to display",
                choices = c("Percent White", "Percent Black",
                            "Percent Hispanic", "Percent Asian"),
                selected = "Percent White"),
    sliderInput("range", 
                label = "Range of interest:",
                min = 0, max = 100, value = c(0, 100))
    ),
  mainPanel(htmlOutput("text")
  )
),
server = function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderUI({
    str1 <- paste("You have selected", input$var)
  })
}
)
)
```

Would like to see the dynamic output as (to be specific it can be n numbers of outputs...)

```
[1] You have selected Percent White
[2] You have selected Percent Asian
[3] You have selected Percent Black
```

Comment: So with the example are you interested to see three text box . if yes, you can use rendertext post creating 3 input box in UI.

Comment: Sorry, if i was not clear however i am looking for dynamic text outputs it can be 3 or 30 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
require(shiny)

runApp(list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("censusVis"),
  sidebarPanel(
    helpText("Create demographic maps with 
             information from the 2010 US Census."),
    selectInput("var", 
                label = "Choose a variable to display",
                choices = c("Percent White", "Percent Black",
                            "Percent Hispanic", "Percent Asian"),
                selected = "Percent White"),
    sliderInput("range", 
                label = "Range of interest:",
                min = 0, max = 100, value = c(0, 100))
  ),
  mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("text")
  )
),
server = function(input, output) {
  val<-reactiveValues()
  val$txt<-""

  observeEvent(input$var,{
    new<-paste("You have selected", input$var)
    val$txt<-paste( val$txt,new,sep='\n')
  })
  output$text <- renderText({
    str1 <- val$txt
  })
}
)
)
```